# How do you call adminInitiateAuth from NodeJS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am trying to call adminInitiateAuth as follows:

```
var params = {
        AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxx',
        AuthParameters: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
    };

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth is not a function

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Other functions such as signUp work when called in the same manner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking into this as well and it appears that the NodeJS AWS sdk that is being provided for the Lambda functions is version 2.4.9, you can check by running:

```
console.log('SDK Version is ' + AWS.VERSION)
```

The version that was released with adminInitiateAuth is version 2.4.11.  I assume that Amazon will update their lambda machines soon but in the meantime you could try adding adding the new sdk manually by

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

and then [zipping up your lambda file with the node_modules folder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

Comment: as a temporary fix, this works - thanks! I've posted in the official forums to draw attention to this here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=734141&#734141

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the current SDK version in Lambda containers predates this API.  The solution is to bundle the SDK version you need into your Lambda zip file.

For applications where reliability is important, you should explicitly bundle all your dependencies in any case.  This isolates your functions from behavior changes or bugs introduced whenever Lambda updates the APIs in the container.